# How can I do a pattern matching with the result of a Map in scala?

Tags: scala

if I have `val myMap = Map("one" ->1, "two" -> 2)` and `myVar = 2` the following does not work, why?

```
myVar match{ 
  case myMap("one") -> // do a certain action
  case _            -> // do another action
}
```

this however works, if instead of `myMap` I have a variable, e.g. `val one = 1` and then `match` becomes

```
myVar match{ 
  case `one` -> "first element"
  case _     -> "second element"
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It makes little sense to me to try and pattern match on a map instead of trying to extract the value from the map.

Comment: I am not trying to extract any value from the map, but rather associate with a certain action, I edited the code to make it clearer

Answer (score 3):

You get an error because for pattern matching we need implementation of unapply method (for more details read [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112)) - in this case there is no unapply method with such parameters in Map:

`def unapply(z: String): Option[Int]`

As an option you can write like this instead:

```
myVar match {
  case x if x == myMap("one") => "first element"
  case _                      => "second element"
}
```